# Set param value in first position of array bean

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I want to know if is possible to set in a bean String Array a property received by an url parameter.

I have this:

The bean, in your FormHandler class:

```
private String[] clientName;
```

The JSP file:

```
<dsp:setvalue bean="ClientFormHandler.clientName" paramvalue="clientName" />
```

In this way, I got this error in my screen:

> **** Error      Wed Jul 06 13:53:06 BRT 2016    Trying to set value of /clientCom/app/formHandlers/ClientFormHandler.clientName, this
>   IllegalArgumentException occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   argument type mismatch

This isn't working, so I tryed this, but without success too...

```
<dsp:setvalue bean="ClientFormHandler.clientName[0]" paramvalue="clientName" />
```

and I got this error

> **** Error      Wed Jul 06 13:55:34 BRT 2016    1467824134007   /atg/dynamo/servlet/dafpipeline/ProtocolSwitchServlet
>   atg.droplet.DropletException: Cannot set elements of a multi-valued
>   prop erty if property is not a List and if it is missing an indexed
>   property method

Can I do something like this in a JSP file, without change the java class?

Tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found an example with an array but I suggest that you work with MVC architecture

you can set your bean parameter by :

1/ adding a form in your JSP where you put the value that you want in an input hidden

```
<form method="post" action="MYSERVLET">
    <input type="hidden" name="VAL" value="NEW_NAME"/>

    <input type="submit" value="click"/>
        </form>
```

2/ create a bean where you put these methods

```
public class bean {
 private String[] clientName ={"tt","bb","gg","ff","tt","gg"};//just for verification

    public String[] getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String[] clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public void NewVal(String newVal, int index){
    this.clientName[index] = newVal; 
     }

     public String getVal( int index){
    return this.clientName[index] ; 
     }
}
```

3/create a servlet(MYSERVLET)

change doPost to

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

 String val  =  request.getParameter("VAL");
 bean Mybean= new bean();
 Mybean.NewVal(val, 0);
 System.out.println("--------------------"+Mybean.getVal(0));
}
```

result :

```
 --------------------NEW_NAME (in server logs)
```

the first position of array bean is changed to "NEW_NAME"